# WCF Deserialization - The deserializer has no knowledge of any type that maps to this name

Tags: wcf, datacontract, deserialization, dynamics-crm-2011

I have a WCF service that communicates with CRM 2011 in the Cloud. I used the provided crmsvcutil.exe to generate entities for all objects in CRM. I have an interface `IProduct` that points to `GetAllProducts()` that needs to return a list of all Products. If I step thru my service when the client (C# console application), the Linq query has the list of products as expected. But when it tries to return it to the calling application, I get an error:

`The InnerException message was 'Error in line 1 position 688. Element 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic:value' contains data from a type that maps to the name 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts:OptionSetValue'. The deserializer has no knowledge of any type that maps to this name. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add the type corresponding to 'OptionSetValue' to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding it to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.'.  Please see InnerException for more details."}`.

This only occurs with complex data types. If I return a simple string or int, no problems there. As a POC that I can return complex types, I created a class called `ComplexPerson`, and a method called `GetPerson(int Id)` to return a simple object. This worked fine (as I had to decorate the class myself).

```
    namespace Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples
    {
        [ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples")]
        public interface IProduct
        {
            [OperationContract]
            [ServiceKnownType(typeof(Product))]
            List<Product> GetAllProducts();

            [OperationContract]
            ComplexPerson GetPerson(int Id);
        }

        public class ProductService : IProduct
        {
            private List<Product> _products;
            private OrganizationServiceProxy _serviceProxy;
            private IOrganizationService _service;

            public List<Product> GetAllProducts()
            {
                _products = new List<Product>();
                try
                {
                    //connect to crm
                        var query = orgContext.CreateQuery<Product>();

                        foreach (var p in query)
                        {
                            if (p is Product)
                                _products.Add(p as Product);
                        }

                        return _products;
                }

                // Catch any service fault exceptions that Microsoft Dynamics CRM throws.
                catch (FaultException<Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault> ex)
                {
                    // You can handle an exception here or pass it back to the calling method.
                    return null;
                }
            }

            public ComplexPerson GetPerson(int Id)
            {
                ComplexPerson person = new ComplexPerson();

                switch (Id)
                {
                    case 2:
                        person.FirstName = "Tim";
                        person.LastName = "Gabrhel";
                        person.BirthDate = new DateTime(1987, 02, 13, 0, 0, 0);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }

                return person;
            }

        }

        [DataContract]
        public class ComplexPerson
        {
            [DataMember]
            public string FirstName;
            [DataMember]
            public string LastName;
            [DataMember]
            public DateTime BirthDate;

            public ComplexPerson()
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how I got it to work. In my case I have three projects:-

- A "service contract" class library project containing the cs file generated by CrmSvcUtil, and my WCF interface (IMyService or whatever). This project references the usual CRM DLLs (Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, MicrosoftXrm.Client, Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Proxy), plus others that these depend on (e.g. System.Data.Services.dll, etc).
- The WCF service project (which references the above project). In here is the .svc that implements the interface in the above project. The project also references the same CRM DLLs as above.
- My client project. This references the above service contract project. It also references two of the CRM DLLs (Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk & Microsoft.Xrm.Client). You might also need to add a couple of dependencies (e.g. System.Runtime.Serialization).

Now add a service reference in the usual way. Now, write your code to instantiate and call an operation on the service proxy. Assuming you need to reference the CRM entity classes, you just need to add a "using xxx;" (where xxx is the namespace you used in the command line of CrmSvcUtil.exe).

Hope this helps
Andy